# Different width for diffent sections in tableview

Tags: iphone

As in screenshot I want to create a grouped tableview to get that kinda look and feel. I am taking UITextfield within every cell. But for Ist 3 rows on above I need that section to be thinner in width. Even in case of rows below cells will not take as much as the width as the tableview takes. What I ma doing I am minimizing the width of tableview from left and setting the background view's color to groupedtableviewstyle color which merges with the tableview background(But the that view background does not contain the scroll property as it is not within the tableview). Is it possible to have different width for different sections in tableview even if I customize the cells? I am open to any other suggestion too. I m not sure taking two different tableview would be a good option or not?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create new contact view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7209780/create-new-contact-view)

Answer (score 2):

One solution to accomplish a screen like the one from your screenshot is to use at least two `UITableView`. Then you can simply change the width of the top table view to match your layout. I don't think you can solve this with a single table view, except by drawing custom cells (which wouldn't be worth the hassle here since there's an easier solution available).

Comment: I have to draw  custome cell in any case to have UITextfield within the tableviewcell. Even if I draw custom cell can the cell's width be different? I mean every cell's width will cover the whole of tableview's width I guess. I guess if it possible to do it using custom cell it will be a more better solution rather than using 2 tableviews I guess. Please advise