# How to decrease the width using IBAFormSection?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uitextfield

I am using IBA Forms Framework and I cant resize the width of the single section? I cant even find the IBA help on internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like it's been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7307935/1835155), there is no easy way to resize a single section width. You might want to find an other way to implement your `tableView`.

IBA Forms Framework is not longer updated. I suggest you to try an other framework such as RETableViewManager, which also provides iOS7 inline pickers.
https://github.com/romaonthego/RETableViewManager